Generalised method by which any $a_r(x)$ can be discovered?
How can I find the $x$ dependent sequence for:
$$ (1+x!)^x = \sum_{r=0}^x a_r x!^r $$
Example, $x=3$:
$$ (1+3!)^3 = 1 + 3!^2/2! + 3!^3(1+1/2!)  $$
Above we can see:
$$a_0(3)=1$$
$$a_1(3)=0$$
$$a_2(3)=1/2!$$
$$a_3(3)=1+1/2!$$
Is there a generalised method by which any $a_r(x)$ can be discovered?

you have $(1+n!)^n = \exp(n \ln(n!)) = \exp( n \sum \ln(k))$ have you already checked it? I'm not sure it goes very far

@julio_es_sui_glace I didn' t try $e^{n \ln(1+n!)}$ and expand the log ... I don't think it would be as helpful imo. The problem comes in with the RHS being solely in x! where as the LHS has x and x! Or are you talking asymptotically? Where $n! >> 1$ .. is also an interesting approach

Yes I was talking asymptotically to get some results on these coefficients

It's worth a shot ... But I'm more curious about the error term in that case

By the binomial theorem
$$
(1+x!)^x= \sum_{k=0}^x \binom{x}{k} (x!)^k=\sum_{k=0}^x \frac{1}{k!(x-k)!} (x!)^{k+1}
$$
Or
$$
(1+x!)^x=1+\sum_{k=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{k!(x-k)!} (x!)^{k+1} + (x!)^x
$$
That gives the value for the coefficients that you have found for the example $x=3$
Notice how any of the formulas above will produce different values for the coefficient, while keeping constant the value of the sum
